# Force sequel to log queries to the same destination as sinatra

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra, sequel

I want initialize Sequel in my Sinatra app with

```
DB = Sequel.sqlite '...', :loggers => [SomeLogger]
```

and I want Sequel to log to the same destination as Sinatra. But it seems like Sinatra logger is available only during request handling (only in instance methods via `request.logger`). I don't want to reopen DB connection on each request, I want to do it only once in my `configure` section.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DB.logger = request.logger` in a before filter would work around the issue if it is only available at runtime without creating a new database connection.

I'm not sure if the Rack/Sinatra logger is available outside a request.  Looking at rack/logger.rb, it appears that a new one is created per request.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it is the only solution.